# dynamic form on php for insert inputs

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

i need help with buildin dynamic form with 2 Column.
one Column get 'names' from DB 2nd Column is insert number from user.
i didnt understand how to build dynamic vribales who get the insert and Passes him to `proccess.php`

This is what I have already tried:

```
<form role="form" action="process.php" method="post">
     <div class="form-group">
         <?php echo '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="<'. $valueArray[0][4]. '>" placeholder="Enter num">'; ?>
         <?php echo '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="<'. $valueArray[0][4]. '>" placeholder="Enter num">'; ?>
     </div>
```

Comment: but i couldnt post the array in proccess.php  and got error

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking, I think you are trying to send an array to your process page based on your names from your database? You can use the `[]` array in the name and num inputs. Also, I am not 100% sure where this comes from `$valueArray[0][4]`:

```
<form role="form" action="process.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="<?php echo $array['name']; ?>[num]" placeholder="Enter Number" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Your process page should receive `$_POST` something like:

```
Array
(
    [joe] => Array
        (
            [num] => 3
        )

    [submit] => submit
)
```

Comment: the $valueArray[0][4] is an array from Previous php code. i insert him data from DB and wanted to add the insert data. i need to use array brcouse the rows on form will be in while loop so i could insert dynamic rows.  i think of using counter in the array for each row. 'counter++' each eteration so the insert data will go to position $valueArray[counter][4]

Comment: the thing is that iam trying to post each time the array and befor submmit i got errorsso i cant realy debug it if iam inserting the data to the php array

Comment: If you post your full code where I can see the loop and such, it would probably be easier to fix.